# Select top 11 that together make up for the highest combined score in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm working on a "football player evaluation" tool for the community of a game I'm playing.
Player information gets stored as shown below (the player's name, his goalkeeper score, defender score, midfielder score, attacker score).

(For the sake of simplicity, this **top4 "team" combination** consists of only 1 goalie, 1 def, 1 mid, 1 att.)

```
+------+--------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| name | Keeper |  Defender | Midfielder| Attacker |
+------+--------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| John |  *7.2* |    6.1    |    7.1    |    3.4   |
| Rick |  1.9   |    9.0    |   *9.2*   |    5.3   |
| Fred |  3.2   |    6.8    |    2.1    |    6.4   |
| Mike |  2.1   |   *8.9*   |    8.7    |    1.2   |
| John |  1.7   |    3.1    |    7.7    |    7.1   |
| Doe  |  4.2   |    8.9    |    8.1    |   *7.9*  |
+------+--------+-----------+-----------+---------+
Team combination with highest total score: John (keeper), Mike (defender), Rick (mid), Doe (att)

Total score: 7.2 + 8.9 + 9.2 + 7.9
```

Lets say the user enters the information for 20 players, he would like to know what 11 players to play, and at what position (there should be 4 defenders, 4 midfielders, and 2 attackers). The higher the **total** score, the better. So by using SQL, I would like to query the db of the 11 best players, that together make up for the highest score.

I realize this might not work in just one query but that's fine. I just can't think of a way to do this, without having to do like 20 queries and comparing the total scores, one by one.

This is what I've tried so far.

**Attempt 1**:
4 different queries, one for each position (keeper, defender, etc)

```
SELECT name,midfielder_score FROM players WHERE id NOT IN (" . implode(',', $alreadyUsedPlayers) . ") ORDER BY midfielder_score DESC LIMIT 4
```

To get the 4 best midfielders. The problem with this approach is that it won't take the fact that the total score would perhaps increase if a good player isn't picked at this stage (when choosing midfielders), but rather left for the attacker pick.

**Attempt 2**:
Combining GRUOP BY with sum

```
SELECT name, SUM(keeper_score) AS totalKeeperScore [...] FROM players GROUP BY name ORDER BY totalKeeperSCore DESC LIMIT 11
```

But I realized that this too has to be done with multiple queries and by comparing.

Any ideas how to go about this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: If understand this right, then Rick, not Mike, is the highest rated defender.

Comment: Individually yes, but consider what matters here thus the overall total score. By not picking Rick as a defender, you gain 0.1 in total score.

Comment: 0.6 in total score, i meant. See why in the example below:

Rick defender: 7.2 + 9.0 + 8.7 + 7.9 = 32.8
Mike defender: 7.2 + 8.9 + 9.2 + 7.9 = 33.2

Answer (score 2):

You can construct all possible teams by using `cross join` with appropriate subqueries.  Then, simply add the scores together and use `order by` and `limit` to choose the best team.

```
select k.name as keeper_name, d.name as defender_name,
       m.name as midfield_name, a.name as attacker_name,
       (keeper + defender + midfield + attacker) as score
from (select name, keeper
      from top4
     ) k cross join
     (select name, defender
      from top4
     ) d cross join
     (select name, midfield
      from top4
     ) m cross join
     (select name, attacker
      from top4
     ) a
order by score desc
limit 1;
```

EDIT:

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72da36/2) is a SQL Fiddle that shows the query working.  This version of the query adds a `where` clause to prevent one person from being in two roles:

```
where k.name not in (d.name, m.name, a.name) and
      d.name not in (m.name, a.name) and
      m.name not in (a.name)
```

Comment: Sound good bud as I'm not too good at SQL, I can't get this to work. Would you mind updating your answer with the exact column names (etc) so I can paste it into my file and see if it yields the right result? k.name for example, is that the right syntax? top4, what's that, not the table name right?

Comment: @Jonathan . . . The column names are based on the sample data you provide at the top of the question.

Comment: Ok so I guess "top4" is the table name then. Are you sure this is completely right, phpMyAdmin's SQL section just keeps on loading, and loading and loading. "#1317 - Query execution was interrupted". Any Ideas? I like the solution though.

Comment: Thanks! The questions asks for top11 though, only using top4 for the sake of simplicity. What changes have to be made in order for this to work with 11 players, 4 defenders, 4 midfielders, 2 attackers?

Comment: @Jonathan . . . You need a new `cross join` for each position (on the right table) and appropriate `where` conditions.  However, because of all the possibilities being considered, you might not be able to run this (depending on the number of players you have).

Comment: Rick appears twice in this result :-(. This appears to be a version of the shortest path problem. Are you sure it's so easily solved in MySQL?

Comment: @Strawberry . . . All my query does is produce every possible combination and choose the one that is best.  Yup, that works.  Just not for very large problems.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for your reply. There will be a maximum of approx. 50 players to choose from, so perhaps you solution would be too demanding for the server? Anyhow, I can't get it to work with 11 players as you propose. Would you mind showing me how you would solve that? Otherwise, I will just go with multiple queries. Not pretty, but sort of working..

Comment: @Jonathan . . . With 50 players, you are looking at about 50^11 combinations.  That's too many for the brute force method to work.

Comment: I thought so, any other solution? Perhaps including several queries?

Comment: @Jonathan . . . As Strawberry points out, this seems to be an unsolved problem in graph theory.  There are some heuristic algorithms, but there is not an easy, guaranteed to be correct solution.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ok I see your point. What I'm trying now, though is fetching 5 def, 5 mid, 3 att (nr of players for each position +1 extra), then trying out all indiv. player at all possible positions, using a forloop like when bubble sorting. Ie: pick the 11 players with the highest overall score out of the above 13, count the total value, move the player at the first pos to the last position in the squad of 11, count the total value. Is it higher than the previous? If so, go on and ignore previous formation. Keep doing this until you find max total value. What do u think of this method?

Comment: @Jonathan . . . It is a reasonable method.  I don't think it is guaranteed to get the optimal result.

Answer (score 0):

I would do 4 queries. Here the psuedo-code that I would use for this:

Create an an associative array:

```
$player["attacker"] 
$player["defender"] 
$player["midfield"] 
$player["keeper"]
```

The make a query for each position, ordering by score, and place it in descending order (highest to lowest).

Take the highest score for the first position and add it to the first array.
Take the second positions highest score, make sure that the player hasn't been selected already for a previous position, 
and if it hasn't, 
then add to the next array.
if the player has been selected, get the next player, and check to make sure they haven't been selected.

Follow this process, checking the highest score and making sure that they player hasn't been assigned a position, till all 4 positions have been filled.

Comment: What you're suggesting's basically what I'm mentioning in Attempt 1. This solution will not yield the best possible squad of 11 players. Why? If one player, for example, is picked in the second round (when choosing defenders), it does not take into account the fact that the overall 11-score might be higher if this player were left for the midfielder pick. See what I mean?

Comment: @Jonathan You return your query results based on the highest ranking, that way the first result, is the highest score, regardless of the position. This way you get the highest score, with the highest position.

Comment: I must have misinterpreted you then. Could you please provide med with a full example so I see what you mean?